# memory leaks in c++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

```
#pragma once


#ifndef SDDS_GIFT_H
#define SDDS_GIFT_H


#include <iostream>

namespace sdds
{
    const int MAX_DESC = 15;
    const double MAX_PRICE = 999.999;
    const int MAX_WRAP = 20;

    struct Gift
    {
        char m_description[MAX_DESC];
        double m_price;
        int m_units;
        int m_wrapLayers;
        struct Wrapping* m_wrap;
    };

    struct Wrapping 
    {
        char* m_pattern;
    };

    void gifting(char*);
    void gifting(double&);
    void gifting(int&);
    bool wrap(Gift& theGift);
    bool unwrap(Gift& theGift);
    void gifting(Gift& theGift);
    void display(const Gift& theGift);
}

#endif








<pre><code>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Gift.h"

    using namespace std;
    namespace sdds
    {
        void gifting(char* m_description) // sending info
        {
            cout << "Enter gift description: ";
            cin.width(MAX_DESC + 1);
            cin >> m_description;
        }
        void gifting(double& m_price)
        {
            cout << "Enter gift price: ";
            cin >> m_price;
            while (m_price > MAX_PRICE || m_price < 0)
            {
                cout << "Gift price must be between 0 and " << MAX_PRICE << std::endl;
                cout << "Enter gift price: ";
                cin >> m_price;
            }
        }
        void gifting(int& m_units)// gifting function
        {
            cout << "Enter gift units: ";
            cin >> m_units;
            while (m_units < 1)
            {
                cout << "Gift units must be at least 1" << std::endl;
                cout << "Enter gift units: ";
                cin >> m_units;
            };
        }


        bool wrap(Gift& m_wrap) {
            if (m_wrap.m_wrapLayers > 0) {
                cout << "Gift is already wrapped!" << endl;
                return false;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Wrapping gifts..." << endl;
                cout << "Enter the number of wrapping layers for the Gift: ";
                cin >> m_wrap.m_wrapLayers;

                while (m_wrap.m_wrapLayers < 1) {
                    cout << "Layers at minimum must be 1, try again." << endl;
                    cout << "Enter the number of wrapping layers for the Gift: ";
                    cin >> m_wrap.m_wrapLayers;
                }
                int i = 0;

                m_wrap.m_wrap = new Wrapping[MAX_WRAP + 1];
                for (i = 0; i < m_wrap.m_wrapLayers; i++) {
                    m_wrap.m_wrap->m_pattern = new char[MAX_WRAP + 1];
                    cout << "Enter wrapping pattern #" << i + 1 << ": ";
                    cin >> m_wrap.m_wrap->m_pattern;
                } // I put struct in a structure
                return true;
            }
            delete[]m_wrap.m_wrap;
            m_wrap.m_wrap = nullptr;
        }

        bool unwrap(Gift& g_unwrap) // unwrap function
        {
            if (g_unwrap.m_wrapLayers > 0) {
                cout << "Gift being unwrapped." << endl;
                g_unwrap.m_wrapLayers = 0;
                g_unwrap.m_wrap->m_pattern = nullptr;

                return true;
            }
            else 
            {
                cout << "Gift isn't wrapped! Can't unwrap." << endl;
                return false;
            }
        }

        void display(const Gift& theGift)
        {
            cout << "Gift Details:" << endl;
            cout << " Description: " << theGift.m_description << endl;
            cout << "       Price: " << theGift.m_price << endl;
            cout << "       Units: " << theGift.m_units << endl;

            if (theGift.m_wrap == nullptr) // this part seems like a problem
            {
                cout << "Unwrapped" << endl;
            }
            else 
            {
                int i = 0;
                cout << "Wrap Layers: " << theGift.m_wrapLayers << endl;
                for (i = 0; i < theGift.m_wrapLayers; i++) {
                    cout << "Wrap #" << i + 1 << ": " << theGift.m_wrap[i].m_pattern << endl;
                }
            }

        }

        void gifting(Gift& gift) //last function
        {
            cout << "Preparing a gift..." << endl;
            gifting(gift.m_description);
            gifting(gift.m_price);
            gifting(gift.m_units);
            wrap(gift);
        }
    }






 </code></pre>

    /***********************************************************************
// Workshop 2: Dynamic Memory & Function Overloading
// Version 2.0
// Date 2020/05/05
// Author Michael Huang
// Description
// Tests Gift module and provides a set of TODOs to complete
// which the main focuses are dynamic memory allocation
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
***********************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include "Gift.h"
#include "Gift.h" // intentional
using namespace std;
using namespace sdds;

void printHeader(const char* title)
{
    char oldFill = cout.fill('-');
    cout.width(40);
    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "|> " << title << endl;

    cout.fill('-');
    cout.width(40);
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout.fill(oldFill);
}
<pre><code>
int main() {

    Gift g1; // Unwrapped Gift

    {
        printHeader("T1: Checking Constants");

        cout << "MAX_DESC: " << sdds::MAX_DESC << endl;
        cout << "MAX_PRICE: " << sdds::MAX_PRICE << endl;
        cout << "MAX_WRAP: " << sdds::MAX_WRAP << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    {
        printHeader("T2: Display Wrapped Gift");

        gifting(g1.m_description);
        gifting(g1.m_price);
        gifting(g1.m_units);
        cout << endl;

        g1.m_wrap = nullptr;
        g1.m_wrapLayers = 0;
        display(g1);
        cout << endl;
    }

    {
        printHeader("T3: Wrap a gift");

        if (wrap(g1))
            cout << "Test succeeded!";
        else
            cout << "Test failed: wrapping didn't happen!" << endl;
        cout << endl << endl;
    }

    {
        printHeader("T4: Re-wrap a gift");

        cout << "Attempting to rewrap the previous Gift: "
             << g1.m_description << endl;

        if (wrap(g1) == false)
            cout << "Test succeeded!";
        else
            cout << "Test failed: gift it's already wrapped, cannot wrap again!";
        cout << endl << endl;
    }

    {
        printHeader("T5: Unwrap a gift");

        cout << "Attempting to unwrap the previous gift: "
             << g1.m_description << endl;
        if (unwrap(g1))
            cout << "Test succeeded!";
        else
            cout << "Test failed: you should be able to unwrap!";
        cout << endl << endl;
    }


    {
        printHeader("T6: Unwrap again");

        cout << "Attempting to un-unwrap the previous gift: "
             << g1.m_description << endl;

        if (!unwrap(g1))
            cout << "Test succeeded!";
        else
            cout << "Test failed: you should not be able to unwrap again!";
        cout << endl << endl;
    }

    Gift g2; // Unwrapped Gift
    {
        printHeader("T7: Prepare another gift");
        g2.m_wrap = nullptr;
        g2.m_wrapLayers = 0;
        gifting(g2);

        cout << endl;
        display(g2);
        cout << endl;
    }

    {
        printHeader("T8: Unwrap the second gift");

        unwrap(g2);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Output matches perfectly but I don't know why memory leaks.. please help me. I am doubting my wrap part but I think there must be something else since deallocation seems fine.

I tried my best but I still cannot see which part is wrong.

I cannot see why my deallocation does not work I tried changing it so many times but nothing works.

Comment: Did you really think that spamming nonsense was what the system meant when it asked you to flesh out your question?

Comment: Where do you `delete[] m_wrap.m_wrap->m_pattern`?

Comment: And you `return` before `delete`ing the other stuff..

Comment: Should I change it to          
             
            }
            delete[]m_wrap.m_wrap;
            m_wrap.m_wrap = nullptr;    return true;

Comment: You should use vectors and strings until you are ready for more advanced memory management

Comment: @user4581301 Good choice!

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```cpp
m_wrap.m_wrap->m_pattern = new char[MAX_WRAP + 1];
```

You allocate memory, but later you only:

```cpp
delete[]m_wrap.m_wrap;
```

Also in your for loop you allocate memory, then get some input and store that inside the pointer, as a memory address. Should you ever dereference that, you will invoke undefined behavior, in practice that may likely will a segfault. You should consider rewriting at least that part from scratch.

Comment: Im really sorry but can you guys help me plz?

Comment: @SeongwonSeo it would be helpful if you'd ask an actual question, the point of this platform is to help each other, questions like 'will anyone help me?' are redundant

Comment: @SeongwonSeo Consider playing a few rounds of Divide and Conquer to reduce the size of the program you need in order to expose the bug you are hunting. Often this alone helps you find the bug by reducing the amount of hiding space for the bug, and if it doesn't it places you in a much better position to ask questions. Use [mre] as inspiration.